# Probability Question: Picking white and black balls.

Tags: probability

I have $B$ black balls and $W$ white balls. What's the probability that the last ball I select is white?

I initially tried thinking of this problem recursively, but realized that there would be quite a lot of conditional probability in that branch.
I also tried solving it when $W = 1$ (ans = $\frac{1}{B + 1}$) and $W = 2$ (ans = $\frac{2}{(B + 1)(B + 2)}$).

Could someone tell me generally how I should go about approaching these problems, thanks.

Comment: Did you mean $B$ *blue* balls?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the correction

Comment: What is your process of selecting the balls? What is "the last ball"?

Comment: If you have (B+W) balls total, and you select them all 1 by 1, without any further conditions, the probability that any ball will be black is $\frac {B}{B+W}$ that goes for the first the last or one from the middle as well.

Comment: Each ball is equally likely to be drawn last, and there are $B$ black ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An enumerative approach will work.

Imagine that the balls are drawn sequentially and arranged in a line in the order of their drawing.  Then it is clear that each possible arrangement is equally likely.

How many arrangements are possible?  Of these, how many end in a white ball?

To answer the first question, note that there are $W+B$ unique positions to distribute the $W$ white balls in the line, so the number of such arrangements is simply $$\binom{W+B}{W}.$$

To answer the second question, restrict the color of one white ball in the last place in line.  This leaves $W+B-1$ positions among which we may distribute the remaining $W-1$ white balls, so the number of arrangements in which the last ball is white is
$$\binom{W+B-1}{W-1}.$$

As these arrangements are equally likely, the desired probability is
$$\frac{\binom{W+B-1}{W-1}}{\binom{W+B}{W}} = \frac{(W+B-1)!}{(W-1)! \, B!} \cdot \frac{W! \, B!}{(W+B)!} = \frac{W}{W+B}.$$

We can see that the same argument can be generalized to more than two colors:  for instance, if there are $B$ black, $W$ white, and $R$ red balls, then there are
$$\binom{W+B+R}{R} \cdot \binom{W+B}{W} = \frac{(W+B+R)!}{W! \, B! \, R!}$$ arrangements in total.  Then we can ask, for instance,

- What is the probability that the last ball is red?
- What is the probability that the last two balls are different colors?
- What is the probability that the first ball has the same color as the last?

You can try to work these out as an exercise.